# Laravel Polymorphic Relation using full model name

Tags: laravel-5, polymorphism

I have a polymorphic relationship set up in Laravel 5.4.  The relationship is working but the query is using the fully qualified model name.

```
select * from `contact_info` 
where `contact_info`.`entity_id` = '25'
and `contact_info`.`entity_id` is not null 
and `contact_info`.`entity_type` = 'App\Modules\User\Model\User' 
limit 1
```

The relationship is set on the User model:

```
/**
 * @description Method handles polymorphic contact relationship.
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphOne
 */
public function contact()
{
    return $this->morphOne('App\Modules\Common\ContactInfo', 'entity');
}
```

and the ContactInfo model:

```
/**
 * @description Method establishes polymorphic relationship (tenant/user).
 * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo
 */
public function entity()
{
    return $this->morphTo();
}
```

The actual table has the values set to 'user', 'tenant' and 'referrer' instead of the model names/namespaces.  I found a little bit of information about relationship maps but don't know if that'll solve my issue here.

Basically I need to find out how to tell the code that `'App\Modules\User\Model\User'` should be `'user'` in the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MorphMaps were the way to go.  I added this to my AppServiceProvider boot method and it started pulling the data as expected:

```
use App\Modules\User;
use App\Modules\Tenant
Relation::morphMap([
    'user' => User::class,
    'tenant' => Tenant::class
]);
```

Query is now:

```
select * from `contact_info`
where `contact_info`.`entity_id` = '25'
and `contact_info`.`entity_id` is not null
and `contact_info`.`entity_type` = 'user' limit 1
```

This [article](https://jjanusch.com/2016/01/morphmap-laravel/) helped me out tremendously.